# I'd like to add a blank space to a specific file in an available

Tags: ansible

I'd like to add a blank space to a specific file in an available.

```
  - name: Remove vulnerabilities
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      insertafter: 'ForceCommand cvs server'
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
      state: present
      backup: yes
    loop:
      - { line: ' ' }
      - { line: 'MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512' }
      - { line: 'KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256' }
      - { line: 'Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr' }
      - { line: ' ' }
      - { line: '### Remove vulnerabilities' }
      - { line: ' ' }
```

The results I want are as follows.

```
...
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

### Remove vulnerabilities
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
...
```

The actual results are as below. There are no blanks. There is no blank between "Forcecommand cvs server" and "##Remove validations".

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
## Remove vulnerabilities
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Seems to be a perfect job for [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way?

I would say that any other way would be better because a requirement to both add an empty line at the start and add several lines makes hard (if even possible) to maintain the idempotency with `lineinfile`: once you have an empty line after the last entry of `ForceCommand cvs server`, Ansible will insert the specified lines on each execution of the playbook. You might try to use `backrefs: true`, `regexp` instead of `insertafter`, and a multiline string as `line` to ease the things and avoid the loop - but you'll end up with the same issue.

Instead, you can use [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) module:

```yaml
---
- name: Add a block to sshd_config
  hosts: localhost  # could be your own choice
  connection: local # could be your own choice
  gather_facts: false # could be your own choice
  tasks:
    - name: Remove vulnerabilities
      blockinfile:
        dest: sshd_config
        insertafter: 'ForceCommand cvs server'
        state: present
        backup: yes
        create: true
        block: |
          
          ### Remove vulnerabilities

          Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
          KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
          MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

This produces:

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK

### Remove vulnerabilities

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

As you can see, it comes with a consequence of having `# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK` and `# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK` markers. But it would be much more reliable and faster than adding the lines one be one. Also, the marker text could be changed using `marker`, `marker_end`, and `marker_begin`.

If you don't want to have the before and end markers in your file, you can follow U880D's recommendation to use `template` module and control the state of the whole file.

Comment: Thank you for your good opinion, faster, no problem with the idiosyncrasies.